# SonarQube leak period UI filter not working anymore

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Tried to create some history by checking out one old revision and setting the **sonar.projectDate** to the date of the corresponding revision. I ran the scanner on that code. Then set the leak period to the same date. Then I checked out the **latest code** and removed the sonar.projectDate. This gave me the *leak period*. So far everything was working properly. In the project UI I was able to see the leak period issues.

**The problem is**: when I click on any of the link issues in the *leak period* the system does not respect the leak period filter and it just showing me all the issues. I can see the below query string param being sent to the server but its actually returning all the issues. I checked the logs and there are no errors in the logs.

```
sinceLeakPeriod=true
```

SonarQube version 5.6.5

Code Analyzer for Java plugin 4.8.0.9441

SonarScanner version 3.0.1.733

Can anyone shed some light on why this filter is not working?

Comment: Looks like you're facing a side effect that is similar to https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8425. I'm referencing this question on the ticket to make sure we test it.